# responsive design via an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

The responsive design on site that is viewed via an iframe does not appear to work. I would like change the width css of the child so that it fits correctly

This is what I have tried:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
                       $("##frameDemo").contents().find("body").css("width","100px");
   });
                    </script> 

    <iframe src="http://www.domain.com?ID=#getincentiveID()#" width="80%" height="100" id='frameDemo'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see a couple of errors there: `$("##frameDemo")` should be `$("#frameDemo")`.

Then, if `src="http://www.domain.com..."` points to an external domain, you can't access the DOM contents with JavaScript.

---

You can fetch a remote page contents with php:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com?ID=#getincentiveID()#';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Then you'll have page contents stored on `$page`.

Comment: Maybe loading the page contents with [php cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), i'll edit my answer

Comment: @Spike not unless you fetch the remote page, process it on the server side and display it